# Browser is not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, firefox, browser

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the application Browser is not working (Firefox is working fine). When I open it, a transparent box opens up with the title bar named Browser & nothing shows. The background can be seen through that opened window. The system hangs out completely ( that’s why I can’t take a screenshot and attach here) and I have to press the power button to switch/restart the system. Any kind of suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Can confirm, exactly the same happens on my 16.04 Dell XPS 9650. It doesn't crash my entire system, though, it just closes the browser window after some time. System doesn't freeze either, just the browser window becomes gray.